# Enable branch protection rules in Github at the Organisation level

Tags: github, github-api, branching-strategy

Is it possible to enable branch protection rules at the organisation level in Github so that all repositories part of that organisation inherit these rules for the applied branches. Right now its really a hassle to enable those same set of rules on a per repo basis for same set of branches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it to work using a simple ruby script that makes use of the GitHub APIs :-

```
require "json"
require "logger"

LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)

def run(cmd)
  LOGGER.debug("Running: #{cmd}")
  output = `#{cmd}`
  raise "Error: #{$?}" unless $?.success?
  output
end


def repos(page = 1, list = [])
  cmd = %Q{curl -s --user "user:pwd" https://github_url/api/v3/orgs/org_name/repos?page=#{page}}
  data = JSON.parse(run(cmd))
  list.concat(data)
  repos(page + 1, list) unless data.empty?
  list
end

repos.each do |repo|
  require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://github_url/api/v3/repos/org_name/#{repo["name"]}/branches/master/protection")
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("user", "pwd")
request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.github.luke-cage-preview+jso"
request.body = JSON.dump({
  "required_status_checks" => {
    "strict" => true,
    "contexts" => [
      "continuous-integration/travis-ci"
    ]
  },
  "enforce_admins" => true,
  "required_pull_request_reviews" => {
    "dismiss_stale_reviews" => true
  },
  "restrictions" => nil
})

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
end
```

Comment: I took this code as a base, made a few adjustments and now it works great, thanks Ashley

Answer (score 4):

Taken from @Ashley 's answers, updated it a bit, with a slight change to reflect current Github's API URLs and, added customization using `GITHUB_ORG` and `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variables.

```
require "json"
require "logger"

$org = ENV["GITHUB_ORG"]
$token = ENV["GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN"]

LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)

def run(cmd)
  LOGGER.debug("Running: #{cmd}")
  output = `#{cmd}`
  raise "Error: #{$?}" unless $?.success?
  output
end


def repos(page = 1, list = [])
  cmd = %Q{curl -s -u dummy:#{$token} https://api.github.com/orgs/#{$org}/repos?page=#{page}}
  data = JSON.parse(run(cmd))
  list.concat(data)
  repos(page + 1, list) unless data.empty?
  list
end

repos.each do |repo|
p(repo["name"])
  require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com/repos/#{$org}/#{repo["name"]}/branches/master/protection")
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("dummy", $token)
request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.github.luke-cage-preview+jso"
request.body = JSON.dump({
  "required_status_checks" => {
    "strict" => true,
    "contexts" => []
  },
  "enforce_admins" => true,
  "required_pull_request_reviews" => {
    "dismiss_stale_reviews" => true
  },
  "restrictions" => nil
})

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
p(response)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

[You now (Apr. 2023) have the notion of rulesets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76038229/6309):

> Rulesets are available in public repositories with GitHub Free and GitHub Free for organizations, and in public and private repositories with GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, and GitHub Enterprise Cloud.

That should allow you to define and enforce **[rules](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets)** for all repositories within an organization.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the Github API's [update branch protection](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#update-branch-protection) endpoint with some kind of automated process to apply branch protection rules to all new branches in your organization.

`PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could use API to successfully enable branch protection one of the branches in one of the repos but how to achieve that for all repos and a set of branches within each repo using it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use the `GET /orgs/:org/repos` endpoint to get all repos in your org, and then use `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches` to get all branches of that repo. Then, combine this with `PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection` to protect all branches of all repos in your org. Does that make sense?